# Wildfly 10 Sys-log-handler printing with Byte_order_mark <feff>

Tags: syslog, wildfly-10, byte-order-mark, rsyslog

I have configured a syslog-handler in WildFly-10 Standalone.xml as below

```
<syslog-handler name="mysyslog">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <hostname value="localhost"/>
    <app-name value="myappserver"/>
    <facility value="local-use-7"/>
</syslog-handler>
```

I have added rules in rsyslog.d as

```
if $programname == 'myappserver'   then /tmp/mysyslog.log
```

When i check the mysyslog file i could see <feff> characters

These characters are appended by Wildfly itself before sending it to rsyslog.

Can you please let me know how to get rid of these from my logs

I referred this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark and it indicated that these are BOM characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is per the [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.4) spec that the BOM is added. A simple workaround is to override the encoding. Unfortunately the standard syslog server management resource doesn't allow for an encoding to be set. There is an [issue filed](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-109) to fix this though.

However you could use a `custom-handler` to override this and use an encoding like `US-ASCII` to change the encoding which would remove the BOM. The following CLI commands should create a syslog handler similar to the one you have configured.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=syslog-pattern:add(pattern="(%t) %s%e")
/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=syslog:add(module=org.jboss.logmanager, class=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.SyslogHandler, named-formatter=syslog-pattern, level=INFO, properties={hostname=localhost, appName="myappserver", facility="LOCAL_USE_7", encoding="US-ASCII", syslogType=RFC5424})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to handle this at rsyslog (possibly because there is no way to handle it at the syslog client), then you can try out the following.

rsyslog supports a parameter called position.from within a property of a template. Use it omit the first three utf-8 BOM indicators.

```
template (name="myTemplate" type="list") {
        property(name="msg" position.from="4")
        constant(value="\n")
}
```

then use the above template conditionally (i.e. if the msg contains the utf-8 BOM indicators).

```
if ($msg startswith "\xef\xbb\xbf") then {
    # use template myTemplate within an action
    ...
} else {
    # Use other template
}
```